# ScrollPane causes my plugin to freeze

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, swt-awt

I use the following code to include an Applet in a ScrollPane into my view for my eclipse plugin:

```
@Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

        composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED);
        final Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        pap = new ProcessingEmbedded2();       
        ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane(ScrollPane.SCROLLBARS_AS_NEEDED);

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(pap, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(panel);
}


public class ProcessingEmbedded2 extends Applet {


}
```

This worked fine in the Eclipse RPC/For plugin developers, but now I tried to run the plugin in another eclipse client. And there the ScrollPane causes the plugin to freeze the whole client. I'm sure it is the ScrollPane, because if I remove this part of the code (i.e. I add the applet directly to the panel without the ScrollPane), the plugin runs as it should. Does anybody know the problem that causes this freeze?

Comment: Try to get thread stack traces with [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) to see where it's at.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are having a platform specific issue GUI issue which is specifically caused by the system attempting to create the ScrollPane.

The test you ran was a good one - removing the ScrollPane to rescue the crash certainly implies that this issue is related , specifically, to that GUI component ... or some component which the ScrollPane depends on.

So the next question is - what is ScrollPane using to build itself ?  Well, the answer, of course, is the AWT - i.e. the java Abstract Windowing Toolkit.

Unfortunately, since AWT components are tied to system components, you might run into a few corner cases where they dont work perfectly well.  What to do in such a scenario ?  One simple solution is to try using a Swing component.

So, since I'm assuming your using AWT's ScrollPane here  - **I would suggest swapping it out with the Swing JScrollPane.**  In my experience, the Swing components are much less likely to result in these sorts of quirks.  However, there are pros/cons associated with each toolkit. But in my experience.. in general, if you have a program that is crashing on an AWT component, the corresponding Swing component might work better.

See : http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26970

Comment: Thanks but... are you sure ? I thought that the swt_awt tag meant you were embedding AWT in an SWT component ?  I don't believe that the ScrollPane class exists in SWT : see http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/platform-swt-dev/msg01564.html